# Workspace on USB or Package on USB

Tags: usb

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,
I am wondering if I can upload my workspace to a USB? I am guessing you cant because of the file structure of ROS but if I can how does one go about that? If I cant , can I move my packages to a USB?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/258287/workspace-on-usb-or-package-on-usb/) by [MechLc](https://answers.ros.org/users/29880/mechlc/) on ROS Answers with karma: 41 on 2017-03-30

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This should be perfectly possible, provided that your medium is formatted with a compatible file system, as permissions (on fi dynamic reconfigure and other executable files) are important in a Catkin workspace.

File systems like FAT, FAT32 and ExFat are not suitable for this. Something like Ext3 or Ext4 or some other FS that supports regular Linux file permissions should work fine.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-03-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1